# Are there worker APIs available in Amazon Mechanical Turk?

Tags: mechanicalturk

I have gone through the documentation of Amazon mechanical Turk. I find that there are options to create/monitor and expire the HITs. All the API's are the requester API's. Are there any worker API's available to select a task or indicate the completion of task?

Comment: Sorry Mat, I dont seem to understand. is there something wrong in the way i posted the question?

Comment: No. You haven't accepted any answer to your previous questions though. So please read the above link if you're not aware of what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the APIs are currently for use on the requester side of mTurk. Workers *must* interact with mTurk via the web interface.

I'm not sure if they are trying to protect their system/users/IP, or if this is just an instance of mTurk starting to show its age. It's one of the oldest AWS services and launched all the way back in 2005!